# What is the difference between create and newAccount in web3js?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain

There are two ways to create account one is web3.eth.accounts.create() and web3.eth.personal.newAccount(); function, When I use newAccount() function account is created in my local geth client but when I used create() function nothing happens.

Edit : 
from web3.eth.accounts.newAccount() to web3.eth.personal.newAccount();;

Answer (score 1):

Everything below is relevant for web3.js v1.x.

There is no such function `web3.eth.accounts.newAccount()`.

There is function `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()`.

The difference is that function `web3.eth.accounts.create()` merely returns an object with an account credentials, while `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()` creates an actual account on the node, via an RPC (remote-procedure call) to a node process (e.g., Parity, Geth, Ganache, etc).

Due to the above, function `create` is synchronous by nature and returns the result immediately, while function `newAccount` is asynchronous by nature and returns a `Promise` object which must be resolved (waited for) in order to obtain the result.

So you will technically be doing:

- `const accountObject = web3.eth.accounts.create(...);`
- `const accountAddress = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount(...);`

Here is the official documentation:

- [`create`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)
- [`newAccount`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount)

Comment: I edited my question, it was my mistake

Comment: @RishabhSingh: No need to apologize for that (whether it was a mistake or not). Just make sure that you understand the answer.

Comment: yaha I understand the answer, but what is the use of create() function if it not actually creating anything?
And I tried newAccount() It create and store the private key in geth node, suppose these node is not locally but remotely somewhere else then my private key is exposed.

Comment: @RishabhSingh: `create` generates an account object with private key and public key. This is actually quite useful, if you want to get yourself a new (random) account. You could also read this in the documentation that I have linked in the answer.