# Which one is more secure and easier to mange among eth.accounts.create, personal.newAccount & eth.accounts.wallet.add

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, accounts

Here are what I knew about them:

1. eth.accounts.create: Generate an address and private key for transaction but did not stored in anywhere.
2. personal.newAccount: Create an account under node, so that we could get these accounts by eth.getAccounts(). But before transaction, the account need to be unlocked.
3. eth.accounts.wallet.add: Create an account and private key stored in memory wallet, can get them by eth.accounts.wallet._accounts.

As the topic, which one is more secure, easier to mange in node and recommended to use for erc20 tokens transfer.

Thanks.

Comment: Kinda duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/71156/16043.

Comment: your link didn't mention about wallet.add

Comment: But it does refer to the other two, so you might want to incorporate into your question some of the insights from that other question.